# WebView save passowrds automatically?

Tags: android, webview

I am working on an WebView based app where I want to save all passowrds, like the way a browser remembers passowrd when writing it once. The problem is that even if I use:

```
webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
```

I still get the alert dialog asking me to save the passowrd. Are there anyway of saving the passowrd without asking the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're also developing a browser that will use the webview... then no, I don't see how this could be possible.

I would see as a security flaw if the browser was able to save a password I typed in without asking me first. I, personally, do not like for the browser to store my password.

Perhaps you are approaching this the wrong way.  What is your intent in saving the password? Maybe you need a "Remember me" type of check box instead?

Comment: I am developing an app that is only using one website and opens the web browser if I open another. If you were going to use the app without saving the password, it would be an awfull lot of wasted time.